# MongoDB getIndex / amend TTL Index

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB and Java.  I have the Mongo 3.0.1 java driver.  I have created a collection, which has a TTL index on it with an expireAfter property.  If I try to amend that value then the code will error with:

```
'exception: Index with name: created_1 already exists with different options'
```

I therefore want to check if the index exists, and check the expireAfter attribute of the index, before deciding whether to drop the index and create a new version of it.

The MongoCollection object only has listIndexes method, which return a collection.  What is the best way to get the index, and check the expireAfter property?

Here is the code that creates the index in the first place.  The problem occurs when I change the value of the EXPIRATION_DAYS constant and rerun the code:

```
private static final Long EXPIRATION_DAYS = Long.valueOf(10);

....

final IndexOptions options = new IndexOptions();
options.expireAfter(EXPIRATION_DAYS, TimeUnit.DAYS);
database.getCollection(errors).createIndex(new BasicDBObject("created", 1), options);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [mongoDB docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/modify-an-index/) the only way to modify an existing index is to drop it and create again.

If you want to get a specific index without looping over the list you can use `findOne` on the `system.indexes` collection:

```
DBObject index = database.getCollection("system.indexes")
                         .findOne(new BasicDBObject("name", "created_1"));
```

If no such index exists then you'll get `null` otherwise you will be able to read the `expireAfterSeconds` property - seconds, not days.

Comment: Thanks.  I think this is probably the best option.

Comment: I still suggest you give the index a custom name and don't rely on MongoDB's automatic index naming.

Comment: Bad news is that `system.indexes` collection is [makred as deprecated since version 3.0](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/system-collections/#<database>.system.indexes). It still works but they may remove (or hide) it in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot update indexes in MongoDB. You have to drop the existing index first and then recreate it with different options.

I suggest you create the index with a specific name. This way you can iterate over the existing indexes and drop the index in question before creating it again.

```
private static final Long EXPIRATION_DAYS = Long.valueOf(10);
private static final String INDEX_NAME = "myIndex";

[...]

MongoCollection<Document> errorsCollection = database.getCollection(errors);
ListIndexesIterable<Document> indexes = errorsCollection.listIndexes();
for (Document index : indexes) {
    if (index.getString("name").equals(INDEX_NAME) && index.getLong("expireAfterSeconds") != TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(EXPIRATION_DAYS, TimeUnit.DAYS)) {
        errorsCollection.dropIndex(INDEX_NAME);
    }
}

IndexOptions options = new IndexOptions()
    .name(INDEX_NAME)
    .expireAfter(EXPIRATION_DAYS, TimeUnit.DAYS);
errorsCollection.createIndex(new Document("created", 1), options);
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is what I thought, but was wondering if there was a better way to get an index rather than getting all indexes and iterating through them.  The java api doesn't provide a method on MongoCollection to getIndex by name, which seems a gap - i.e. there is a method to drop index by name.

Comment: @robjwilkins It's not only the Java API that missing getIndex method. Even the mongo shell doesn't provide it. I created a feature request for that https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DRIVERS-244

Answer (score 2):

According to the [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/collMod/), you've been able to run a command in the Mongo shell like the following since v2.2:

```
db.runCommand({collMod: "<collection-name>",
               index : { keyPattern: { "<indexed-field>": 1 },
                         expireAfterSeconds: <new-value> }})
```

Translating that to use the [MongoDB Java driver](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/), you get:

```
Document collModCmd =
  Document.parse("{collMod: '<collection-name>', " +
                 " index : { keyPattern: {'<indexed-field>': 1}, " +
                 "           expireAfterSeconds: <new-value> }}");
Document commandResult = db.runCommand(collModCmd);
```

Seems to work fine for me on a test collection.

Comment: Was looking for a solution with Java. Worked like a charm.